# Regressing changes in yield/yield curve

Tags: fixed-income, regression, yield-curve

If I'm regressing changes in individual points along a yield curve and measures of changes in level/slope/curvature of that yield curve against the returns of some random variable then do I want to use % changes in yields or absolute changes in yields (eg yield change from 1% to 0.95% would be -0.05)?

I am new to fixed income and my experience with volatility tells me that I should use absolute changes since it is already measured in %.  For example, the R^2 is much higher when regressing 1-month vix futures changes in points against spx returns than % change against spx returns.  However, since I'm new to fixed income I'm running myself in circles (because I don't know what I don't know).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What I usually see (and do) is working with absolute changes, i.e. $r(t)=R(t)-R(t-1)$. This depends on the rates regime as well, of course. I have seen insurance companies (historically) model their rates with lognormals (r(t)=\ln(R(t)/R(t-1))$ until 2011/2021, then with a shifted lognormal model until 2018+, and with normals (your suggestion) now....

Comment: There's an old RBS piece by Rebonato from 2010, "Dependence of Magnitude of Rate Moves on Rates Levels" which is relevant to your question. At the present time, I would use differences as described by @Kermittfrog.

Comment: You may find my answers [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61372/what-is-the-best-way-to-interpret-changes-in-treasury-yields/61373#61373) and [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/47225/stress-testing-fixed-income-yield-curve-with-nelson-siegel/47227#47227) relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The convention in fixed income is for everything to be quoted in yield or basis-point terms, leaving it incumbent on the user to derive a correct price thus. Note that this convention is a convention, that is in no way profit-altering!

As such, it simply seeks to minimise confusion in the face of complexity... which assumes that the tiny majority who are genuinely financially-literate feel the same, which they almost certainly don't ;-)
DEM

Answer (score 0):

most rates people speak in terms of basis points and basis point volatility, while some popular products still trade in yield vol (%yield for treasury futures options). Regardless it's an easy conversion between the two. I recommend doing your regressions in basis points. While it's a point of discussion, I'd argue that the fed doesn't work in % of yield and you shouldn't either.

Comment: Options on Treasury futures are based on price vol.

Comment: that's correct, my mistake.